# How to make axis text element relate to a fill level

Tags: r, ggplot2

How does one make the axis.text() element relate to the levels of a plot in R rather than values? I am trying to make this graph:
[image]

So far I have made this:

[image]

My question is how to get the y axis text to represent the data levels rather than their values, and how to get the data values to appear in the middle of the data levels instead of at their value, as in the example above.

Here is a snippet of the code

```
Kategorie1_G <- c(7.7, 1.0, 8.7)
Kategorie2_G <- c(8.4, 4.4, 12.8)
KNamen_G <- c("Category 1", "Category 2")
UKNamen_G <- c("Inbound", "Outbound", "Total")
col_G <- c("white", "blue", "black")
Value <- c(Kategorie1_G, Kategorie2_G)
  Level <- factor(rep(length(Kategorie1_G):1, length(KNamen_G)))
  Name <- factor(rep(KNamen_G, each=length(Kategorie1_G)), levels=KNamen_G)
  Data <- data.frame(Value, Name, Level)
ggplot(data=Data, aes(Name, Value)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill=Level),
             width = 0.6, colour ="white") +
    geom_text(label = format(Value, big.mark = ".", scientific = FALSE), nudge_y = 0, 
              vjust = 0, color = "black", size = 5)  +
    scale_fill_manual(values=col_G) +
    theme(aspect.ratio = 1.2) +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(angle = 0, size=16, hjust=-10, vjust=-10),
          axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_text(size=16),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_text(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          axis.line.y=element_blank(),
          legend.position="none") +
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0,15))
```

Comment: You have only two `UKNamen_G`, but there are three levels.

Comment: Sorry, edited it.

Comment: Your code does not produce the figure you posted. And also, it's not really a minimally reproducible example. You can use the `breaks` and `labels` options in `scale_y_continuous` to place the words "inbound" and "outbound" wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two questions at once. And I don't fully understand the second one. So I'll only answer the first.

To place words along the y axis, just use `breaks` to specify where the words should be placed and then specify the actual words with `labels`, like so:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(4, 7),
                     labels = c("label at 4", "label at 7"),
                     name = NULL) + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]